# Randomly generate a Self-Avoiding Polygon on an M-by-N-sized grid

Tags: algorithm, polygon

I need an algorithm to randomly generate a self-avoiding polygon on a 2D grid, within size (M x N).
The defination of the self-avoiding polygon is at [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingPolygon.html).
That is a closing path (ring) on a grid, who does not interact itself.

If possible, the algorithm would better generate any possible self-avoiding polygons with equally probability.

I can thought out the maze-generation algorithm using Depth-first search to generate a tree [wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm), then the tree's rounding perimeter is just a self-avoiding polygon.
But this approch cannot generate all possible self-avoiding polygons, such as the biggest rectangle (M x N) within the grid.

[image: A example]

Comment: Does the algorithm need to generate all or randomly create one

Comment: @RanikaNisal Creating one is alright.

Answer (score 0):

The following Algorithm will generate 1 closed polygon. It doesn't use any graph theory concepts though. As a language wasn't mentioned I have written the code in python. It can easily be changed to find all polygons if needed.

```
import random

currentpath = [(0,0)]
length = 2 #any actual grid is 3x3 length is 2 however
height = 2
initial = (0,0)
allpaths = []

def backtrack(currentpath,currentnode):
    if(currentnode == (0,0) and len(currentpath)>1):
        return True
    directions = [0,1,2,3]
    while(len(directions) > 0):
        x = random.choice(directions)
        if(x == 0):
            #left
            nextnode = (currentnode[0] + 1, currentnode[1])
            if(currentnode[0] == length or (nextnode in currentpath and nextnode != (0,0)) or (nextnode ==(0,0) and len(currentpath)<4)):
                directions.remove(x)
                continue
            else :
                currentpath.append(nextnode)
                if(backtrack(currentpath,nextnode)):
                    return True
                else :
                    directions.remove(x)
                    currentpath.remove(nextnode)
                    continue
        if(x == 1):
            #right
            nextnode = (currentnode[0] - 1, currentnode[1])
            if (currentnode[0] == 0 or (nextnode in currentpath and nextnode != (0,0)) or (nextnode ==(0,0) and len(currentpath)<4)):
                directions.remove(x)
                continue
            else:
                currentpath.append(nextnode)
                if(backtrack(currentpath,nextnode)):
                    return True
                else :
                    directions.remove(x)
                    currentpath.remove(nextnode)
                    continue
        if(x == 2):
            #up
            nextnode = (currentnode[0], currentnode[1] + 1)
            if (currentnode[1] == height or (nextnode in currentpath and nextnode != (0,0)) or (nextnode ==(0,0) and len(currentpath)<4)):
                directions.remove(x)
                continue
            else:
                currentpath.append(nextnode)
                if(backtrack(currentpath,nextnode)):
                    return True
                else :
                    directions.remove(x)
                    currentpath.remove(nextnode)
                    continue
        if(x == 3):
            #down
            nextnode = (currentnode[0], currentnode[1] - 1)
            if (currentnode[1] == 0 or (nextnode in currentpath and nextnode != (0,0)) or (nextnode ==(0,0) and len(currentpath)<4)):
                directions.remove(x)
                continue
            else:
                currentpath.append(nextnode)
                if(backtrack(currentpath,nextnode)):
                    return True
                else :
                    directions.remove(x)
                    currentpath.remove(nextnode)
                    continue
    if(len(directions)==0):
        return False

backtrack(currentpath,initial)
print (currentpath)
```

Comment: Good! But one point, the random walk method seems to generate smaller polygons with high probabilities and larger polygons with lower probabilities. How can I raise the chance for large and complexy polygons?

Comment: And the worst case of this method is EXTREMELY costly. Think about this case, if the space is 100 X 100, with bad luck when starting with a wirlpool like shape, the tail will never meet the head unless traverse all possible paths until trace back.

Comment: The algorithm this is based of is the constraint satisfaction problem (CSP). You can add more constraints to the constraints list if you wish to reduce time complexity. If you had an algorithmic way to find wether you are definitly in a swirl for instance. The advantage of this approach is that you can add constraints as you wish and avoding going in paths . As for finding smaller paths I really dont have an answer. Selecting random directions was so as to find a truly random path.

Comment: As of now I have 2 constraints for each direction. (1) checking wether we are at an edge which prevents us going to that direction and (2) checking wether we already have the next node in our current path.

Comment: When running @Ranika Nisal 's code in practice, I often get a dead loop if `length >= 4 height >= 4`.